# Python skip operation on first line of file

Tags: python, loops, python-3.5

I have a csv file which looks like following:

```
CCC;reserved;reserved;pIndex;wedgeWT;NA;NA;NA;NA;NA;xOffset;yOffset;zOffset
0.10089,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.8,-0.7,1999998
0.1124,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1.2,1.8,-3.9
```

I am using the `fileinput` method to do some operation in the file, but I want to skip the operation on the first (header) line, though still keeping it there. I have tried using `next(f)` and `f.isfirstline()`, but they delete the header line. I want to keep the header line intact, though not doing any operation on it.

```
with fileinput.input(inplace=True) as f:
    #skip line
    for line in f:
    .
    .
```

Comment: Could you share the expected output and what you do in the `for`-loop (no problem if it's shortened, just enough to see what you basically do)? Please also have a look at [mcve]. That includes some hints to actually make your question answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to easily keep track of the line numbers:

```
for linenum, line in enumerate(f):
    if linenum == 0:
        # 'line' is the header line
        continue

    # 'line' is a data line
    # ...
```

Comment: I tried using `enumerate` but it still deletes the header line. [Here](https://github.com/AnanDvd/MPI-Pigino/blob/master/csv_edit_Mareike_yesHeader_linenum.py) is my script

Comment: Why are you using `inplace=True` if you aren't aware that you have to write output back to the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter` and skip it with `next`:

```
with fileinput.input(inplace=True) as f:
    iterF = iter(f)
    print next(iterF)#skipping computation but printing data
    for line in iterF:
        #...
```

This way you will just get the overhead of creating the iterator once, but will not create the indexes nor compute an `if` in each iteration loop as in @JonathonReinhart solution (wich is also valid).

Comment: I tried using `iter` and `next`, but it still deletes the header line. [Here](https://github.com/AnanDvd/MPI-Pigino/blob/master/csv_edit_Mareike_yesHeader.py) is my script

Comment: @AnandDwivedi, what do you want to do with the info in the header, print it?